# Can we make calls to any number in Android Wear 2.0?

Tags: android, wear-os

I'm developing Android Wear application where I'm working on a feature which facilitates in calling 911 in case of emergency. I haven't seen the android wear 2.0 yet.

I know there is internet connectivity and Google Play Store available in 2.0 but I have no information if we can also make calls to any number in 2.0. Can someone please answer my question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can make phone calls if you have a device with cellular capabilities (e.g. the LG Watch Urbane 2nd Edition LTE) and a SIM card.

In code it might look something like this:

```
 Uri number = Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber);
 Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, number);
 startActivity(callIntent);
```

This doesn't require any permissions since it's not actually placing the call, just opening the dialer on the wearable. As far as I know it should also be possible to make a phone call without user confirmation, but this requires handling runtime permissions.