# Android Wear is not opening dial pad via intent

Tags: android, kotlin, android-wear-2.0

I am working on an `android wear` project, I am facing an issue while opening the dialing activity via `intent`. The problem is that `Intent` is opening the call history instead of the dial pad.

**Code snippet**

```
val callIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL)
callIntent.data = Uri.parse("tel:0526722293")
context.startActivity(callIntent)
```

I have checked different stack-overflow post but still facing the same issue.

[Can we make calls to any number in Android Wear 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45730369/can-we-make-calls-to-any-number-in-android-wear-2-0)

[How to make a phone call using intent in Android wear?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48266050/how-to-make-a-phone-call-using-intent-in-android-wear)

Is there anything that, I have to do more for android wear

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing the app one an emulator, try the same on a physical watch. If the issue still persists, you might want to check the following:

1. Do the app have required permissions
2. Is this specific to a device/OS version

Ref:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/telecom/selfManaged#constraints
https://developer.android.com/wear/releases?hl=ko

Comment: It is happening on physical device and not specific to device OS. I had checked on Moto 360 (rounded), Oppo (square) watch. as per as the permission concern, I am using the 'ACTION_DIAL' which doesn't need runtime permissions

Comment: There are some changes in latest API levels in accessing third party packages, did you think that could be the reason?